# Display all images from storage in Firebase

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to display all my images from **Firebase Storage** on a table. I seem to be having a hard time doing so in **JavaScript**. It gives me an error:

> Firebase Storage: Object 'Item_Images/' does not exist.

```
var fbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Item Posts");
var storage = firebase.storage().ref();
var storageRef = storage.child("Item_Images/");

fbRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var name = snap.child("ItemName").val();
    var price = snap.child("Price").val();
    var category = snap.child("Category").val();
    var description = snap.child("Description").val();
    var image = storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
        var test = url;
        document.querySelector('img').src = test;
    })

    $("#tableBody").append("<tr><td>" + image + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + category + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>" );
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class="heading">
        <td width="20%">Image</td>
        <td width="20%">Name</td>
        <td width="10%">Price</td>
        <td width="15%">Category</td>
        <td width="35%">Description</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- display data here -->
    <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my database:

[image: database]

and here's my current HTML Table:

[image: HTML Table]

Answer (score 1):

Uhh.. it turns out that I have fixed this on my own. I will be posting the answer here so it might help other people.

```
var fbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Item Posts");
//removed the storage reference

fbRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var name = snap.child("ItemName").val();
    var price = snap.child("Price").val();
    var category = snap.child("Category").val();
    var description = snap.child("Description").val();
    //got the string URL from the database
    var image = snap.child("Image").val();

    //concatenated the img tag using the image variable at the top
    $("#tableBody").append("<tr><td><img src=" + image + "/img></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + category + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>" );
});
```